# creating a form with multiple photo upload (PLupload)

Tags: jquery, forms, plupload

I'm creating a form with a few fields, like "title", "date", "textarea" and an option to upload photos with PLupload.

But what is the best way to upload the form and attach the photo's to the right post in my DB?

My current method is, when click on the Save button:

```
function save() { // javascript function

    // step 1. do an empty jquery post, so I get a (database) ID of my new post

    // step 2. start PLupload upload, with as parameter the ID from step 1 (using multipart_params in PLupload)

    // step 3. when PLupload is ready, update the form with the complete content (title, date, textarea.

}
```

But this method is a little bit complex for a simple form. I'm searching for a more easy way. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I've come across many times in the past myself (with several ajax uploaders).

One solution I've come up with is to generate an id containing the date and time and a random number and then insert this id in both the posts table and the photos table. So the posts table would have an extra "files_id" column, and the photos table as well.

```
<?php
$files_id = date('ymdhis').rand(0,9999999999);
?>
```

Might not be a 100% failsafe solution, so I would be curious if there are any other suggestions.